# Pseudo-parallel WCF service calls as fast as possible

Tags: .net, wcf

I have the following requirement: 14 WCF calls should be performed "in parallel" and "at the same time" in order to start "synchronized" videos on 14 displays.

Please note the quotation marks, as I am fully aware that this is not really possible, but I want to get as close as possible!

I experimented with background threads and the Parallel-statement and results are pretty good most of the time. However, sometimes there is a larger delay between every service call.

My code looks like this:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Parallel.For(0, myChannelControllers.Length, n =>
    {
        try
        {
            IMyService channel = myChannelControllers[n].GetChannel();

            channel.VideoWallPlay(...);

            myChannelControllers[n].CloseChannel(channel);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }

    });

};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Any ideas for optimization?

Comment: I would acquire the channel in one loop.  Then play and close in another.  Why take the lag of GetChannel?

Answer (score 0):

In case it was the answer.  Acquire the channel in one loop. Then play and close in another. Why take the lag of GetChannel?